# Relative paths from inside a file: `../` --> parent directory vs `./` --> file itself?

Tags: ruby, file

Suppose file_a and file_b live in the same directory, and file_a contains a `require` statement that `require`s file_b. The way to do this seems to be like so:

```
require File.expand_path('../file_b', __FILE__)
```

But kind of expected it to look like this instead:

```
require File.expand_path('./file_a', __FILE__)
```

I played around with it and sure enough, the `./` version doesn't work and the `../` version does. The `./` version returns a path like `path/to/file_a/file_b`. Is the concept that code inside file_a lives inside that file, much like file_a "lives" inside it's parent directory? I feel like I just answered my own question, but want to make sure I'm understanding this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **File.expand_path(file_name [, dir_string] )  ->  abs_file_name**
>
> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point.

`File.expand_path` treats the second (optional) parameter as `dir_string`, it doesn't care whether it is actually a directory or not. So it's your job to make sure the second parameter passed in be a path to a directory.

If you want preserve the `./file_a` part, you may change the second parameter passed in:

```
require File.expand_path('./file_a', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```